# Why will this code work normally, but when I export it as an exe it stops working?

Tags: python-3.x

This is a snippet of code from a project I'm working on, and this specific part works perfectly when I just run it normally, but as soon as I export it to an exe (using auto py to exe) it just desn't work.

```
def exportData():
startDate = datetime.strptime((str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y')) +"-"+ str(settings["monthPeriod"][0]) +"-"+ str(settings["periodDays"][0])),"%Y-%m-%d").date()
while True:
    try:
        endDate = datetime.strptime((str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y')) +"-"+ str(settings["monthPeriod"][0] + settings["monthPeriod"][1]) +"-"+ str(settings["periodDays"][1])),"%Y-%m-%d").date()
        break
    except ValueError: 
        settings["periodDays"][1] -= 1

selectedOptions = []
for i,v in enumerate(checkedVars):
    if v.get() == 1:
        selectedOptions.append(i)

columnNames = []

for i in selectedOptions:
    columnNames.append(shiftLoggerColumns[i])

wantedColumns = logged_shifts[columnNames].values.tolist()

start_of_week = datetime.date(datetime.now()) - timedelta(days = datetime.date(datetime.now()).weekday())
end_of_week = start_of_week + timedelta(days = 6)

finalOutputList = []

if "Date" in columnNames:
    if selectedPeriod.get() == "Past Week":
        for i in wantedColumns:
            if datetime.strptime(i[0], "%d-%m-%Y").date() >= start_of_week and datetime.strptime(i[0], "%d-%m-%Y").date() <= end_of_week:
                finalOutputList.append(i)
    elif selectedPeriod.get() == "Past Month":
        for i in wantedColumns:
            if datetime.strptime(i[0], "%d-%m-%Y").date().month == settings["monthPeriod"][0] and endDate >= datetime.strptime(i[0], "%d-%m-%Y").date() >= startDate:
                finalOutputList.append(i)
    elif selectedPeriod.get() == "Past Year":
        for i in wantedColumns:
            if datetime.strptime(i[0], "%d-%m-%Y").date().year == datetime.date(datetime.now()).year:
                finalOutputList.append(i)

if selectedPeriod.get() == "":
    messagebox.showerror("Shift Logger", "Please select a period of time for the information you wish to export.")

fileName = "Exported Overview "+str(datetime.date(datetime.now()))+".xlsx"

exportDataframe = pd.DataFrame(finalOutputList, columns = columnNames)
exportDataframe.to_excel(fileName, sheet_name = ("Data exported on "+str(datetime.date(datetime.now()))), index = False)

shutil.move(fileName, os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop'))

messagebox.showinfo("Shift Logger", "Successfully exported data.")
```

This code is using this interface:

```
exportTitle = ttk.Label(exportTab, text = "Export Data", font = "Arial 20 bold")
exportTitle.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=(5,0),pady=(10,0),sticky="w")

shiftLoggerColumns = []

for i in logged_shifts.columns:
    shiftLoggerColumns.append(i)

selectedPeriod = StringVar()

periodOptionFrame = ttk.Frame(exportTab)
periodOptionFrame.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="w",padx=5)

exportPeriods = ["Past Week","Past Month","Past Year",]

exportPeriodRadiobuttons = []

for i,v in enumerate(exportPeriods):
    exportPeriodRadiobuttons.append(ttk.Radiobutton(periodOptionFrame, text = v, value = v, variable = selectedPeriod))
    exportPeriodRadiobuttons[i].grid(row=0,column=i,padx=10,pady=(10,0))

checkedVars = []

for i,v in enumerate(shiftLoggerColumns):
    checkedVars.append(IntVar())

exportOptionButtons = []

exportOptionsFrame = Frame(exportTab)
exportOptionsFrame.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

for i,v in enumerate(shiftLoggerColumns):
    exportOptionButtons.append(ttk.Checkbutton(exportOptionsFrame, text = v, var = checkedVars[i]))
    
row, column = 0, 0

for i in exportOptionButtons:
    i.grid(row=row,column=column,sticky="w",padx=10,pady=5)
    i.state(['!alternate'])
    column += 1
    if column == 3:
        column = 0
        row += 1

exportButton = ttk.Button(exportTab, text = "Export To Desktop", command = exportData)
exportButton.grid(row=3,column=0,sticky="w",pady=(35,0),padx=10)

checkedVars[0].set(1)
exportOptionButtons[0].config(state = "disabled")
exportPeriodRadiobuttons[0].invoke()
```

Which is all part of a larger program, however it works fine in isolation and also when integrated during testing, until I try pressing the export button when running as an exe.

By not work, I mean it just doesn’t do anything. No error or anything like that, which is why I’m a bit confused.

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get an error?